# Wordpress custom search results page not showing excerpt

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I have a custom content-searchresults.php page. However for some reason its not showing the excerpt, but other amends I make this on this are pulled through so it is using this template.

Below is my code.

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>


        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() && ! post_password_required() && !is_single() ) : ?>


            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" >
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'img-responsive'));   ?>
            </a>


        <?php endif; ?>

        <div class="clearfix">
            <header class="entry-header ">
                <?php if ( in_array( 'category', get_object_taxonomies( get_post_type() ) ) && CrippsTheme_categorized_blog() ) : ?>
                <div class="entry-meta">
                    <span class="cat-links"><?php echo get_the_category_list( _x( ', ', 'Used between list items, there is a space after the comma.', 'CrippsTheme' ) ); ?></span>
                </div>
                <?php
                    endif;

                    if ( is_single() ) :
                        the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
                    else :
                        the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h1>' );
                    endif;
                ?>

            </header><!-- .entry-header -->
        </div>


    <div class="entry-summary clearfix">
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
    <div class="clearfix">
    <a class="read-more" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" >
        Read more
    </a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasnt that it wasnt showing the excerpt it was that I had an advanced custom field with the main copy in. To show an advanced custom field excerpt i used the following.

Add to functions.php

```
function custom_field_excerpt() {
global $post;
$text = get_field('main_copy');
if ( '' != $text ) {
    $text = strip_shortcodes( $text );
    $text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
    $text = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $text);
    $excerpt_length = 45; // 45 words
    $excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' ' . '[...]');
    $text = wp_trim_words( $text, $excerpt_length, $excerpt_more );
}
return apply_filters('the_excerpt', $text);
}
```

Then add the following to where you would like the excerpt to show:

```
<?php echo custom_field_excerpt(); ?>
```